# How to interpret this Apple App review crash report section?

Tags: ios, crash-reports, xcode15

Can someone explain this section of a crash report we have received from an iOS app submission that crashes on launch.

Review device details:

Device type: iPhone
OS version: iOS 17.0.3

```
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0


Thread 0 name:  com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0    libsystem_kernel.dylib                  0x20056101c __pthread_kill + 8
1    libsystem_pthread.dylib                 0x222b06680 pthread_kill + 268
2    libsystem_c.dylib                       0x1c195fbb0 abort + 180
3    libc++abi.dylib                         0x222a34660 abort_message + 132
4    libc++abi.dylib                         0x222a2462c demangling_terminate_handler() + 348
5    libobjc.A.dylib                         0x1b1de6d34 _objc_terminate() + 144
6    libc++abi.dylib                         0x222a33a24 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
7    libc++abi.dylib                         0x222a339c8 std::terminate() + 56
8    libdispatch.dylib                       0x1c18a7314 _dispatch_client_callout + 40
9    libdispatch.dylib                       0x1c18aad48 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 284
10   FrontBoardServices                      0x1d1a889ec __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 52
11   FrontBoardServices                      0x1d1a8896c -[FBSMainRunLoopSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 240
12   FrontBoardServices                      0x1d1a88844 -[FBSMainRunLoopSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 28
13   CoreFoundation                          0x1b99b0acc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
14   CoreFoundation                          0x1b99afd48 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 176
15   CoreFoundation                          0x1b99ae55c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 340
16   CoreFoundation                          0x1b99ad238 __CFRunLoopRun + 828
17   CoreFoundation                          0x1b99ace18 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608
18   GraphicsServices                        0x1fc4715ec GSEventRunModal + 164
19   UIKitCore                               0x1bbdbb2fc -[UIApplication _run] + 888
20   UIKitCore                               0x1bbdba938 UIApplicationMain + 340
21   Ordre                                   0x10459c968 main + 18792 (main.m:16)
22   dyld                                    0x1dc197d44 start + 2104
```

We have not been able to replicate in Xcode or in TestFlight. We use Xcode Version 15.0 (15A240d)